# Executing .git commands inside electron without having git installed

Tags: node.js, git, electron

I am trying to get some git information (for instance command hash) from an electron app. I am reading a file from a certain path and I want to check if this file inside a repo then I will get the super project and get the commit hash.

This is doable if the git is installed on the machine , but if not then this will fail.
I can deal with file paths and get to .git folder and get information from it, but still I prefer if there is another way.

I tried to install npm nodegit, but it has its problems with electron and webpack.

Also there is git-revision but its methods are simple and I need more functionalities (like getting the super project )

Is there a way or a library to achieve that if we need to run the project on machine with no git installed on it?

Comment: The functionalities you need are unclear. What does it mean to "get the super project"?

Comment: if i am in a sub-module then I need the parent repo ..

Comment: I have no experience with electron but if you have access to the file system the options are basically either to create a portable git installation somewhere, to reimplement git yourself, or to use a library that reimplements git for you. If the libraries don't do the trick, and you only need some simple functionality, then working directly with the files in the `.git` folder(s) is probably easiest

Comment: okay thanx I will try ismorphic-git